# how to apply print stylesheets in email templates as the <style> tag gets discarded by the email clients?

Tags: html, css

I am developing HTML email templates, where the page also supports *Print* feature. The style of the HTML document should differ, when one prints the same. So, I have added an `internal` stylesheet for print (only) and rest of the styling is being leveraged by the `inline` styles, using as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
        /* print related styles */
    }
</style>
```

I know that `@media print {..}` and `media="print"` isn't supported by all the email clients and have no issue with them, but the **issue** is -: **the styles which I have added for print, are being removed entirely by the clients**.
Thus I am unable to target the DOM by providing a different styles for print.

Comment: yes try to use inline coding. In Email template only inline coding is working

Comment: @PardeepPathania, but how should one target `print` styles?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this.
Create a copy of the template for print version and upload it in the server. Then put a link to it from the email template.
I am not sure whether this will be the exact solution.

If you can't keep two copies, Put a link to web url of the same email template itself. Now clicking on this will open the same template in a fresh window like a normal web page. Here it will support all  tags and media queries. So all the required styles only for print should be in a  tag out side body. So this will be available only in the print version opened in fresh window. those styles required for email template should be inline so it will support in any email client.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by many Emails like Google and others, They remove style / Script and other stuff...

You need to figure away to use inline styling instead

Comment: I am already using `inline` styles for DOM, but I am unable to provide styles on `print`. Any idea?

Comment: I think, this post should be as a part of comments and not as an answer, as you haven't given an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Agree, but Your question was the <style> tag is removed... i think you also need to edit the question to how to apply `print` styles in email :)

Comment: I thought people will read the description too, anyways, I have edited the question too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if something like this `@media print { body { display:none } }` does not work then the email client does not support print media queries. If the email client removes it or not is irrelevant :/

Something that came to mind just now, this probably wouldn't work but you could try targeting [A4 sizes](http://www.a4papersize.org/a4-paper-size-in-pixels.php) using media queries which is probably better supported so, something like `@media (max-width: 595px) {}` which refers to **A4 - 72 PPI**

Try that and let me know if it works please :)

Comment: Pons Purushothaman has a good point also, you can just create a link to the print version on your website and name it: "Click here to print"

Comment: yeah, that idea is good by @PonsPurushothaman, but I have many email templates, and creating a copy of each of them is neither possible nor allowed.

Comment: I used to try to create HTML email templates, I gave up very soon afterwards when I saw the lack of support even for HTML5 :P

Comment: I am working for the first time and also exploring the drawbacks apart from delivering the project.